# Intuitive derivation of formulas for finding the i-th child of a node in a traversal-numbered complete tree

Tags: algorithm, math, tree

In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39071313/6732794) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39070461/6732794) question, I used two formulas that I arrived at by ad-hoc means, and I am at a loss for a simple explanation for why these formulas work. Here is the problem in full:

Consider a [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#perfect) or complete *K*-ary tree of height *H* where every node is labeled by their rank in a breadth-first traversal, and the its dual where every node is labeled in depth-first order. Here is an example with K=2, H=2:

```
    _ 0 _                 _ 0 _
   /     \               /     \
  1       2             1       4
 / \     / \           / \     / \
3   4   5   6         2   3   5   6
```

For the BF-ordered tree, the *i*-th child of a node *N* at depth *D* is given by:

`K*N + 1 + i`

For the DF-ordered tree, the *i*-th child of a node *N* at depth *D* is given by:

`N + 1 + i*step, where step = (K^(H - D) - 1) / (K - 1)`

What is an intuitive explanation for these formulas?

The BF-ordered formula makes sense to me when looking at any hand-drawn example, but I can't put into words why it works. In the DF-ordered case, the best I can come up with is this:

> For a node *N* at depth *D* in a DFS-numbered *K*-ary tree of height *H*, its first child is simply *N+1* because it is the next node to be visited in a depth-first traversal. The second child of *N* will be visited directly after visiting the entire sub-tree rooted at the first child (*N+1*), which is itself a complete *K*-ary tree of height `H - (D + 1)`. The size of any complete, *K*-ary tree is given by the sum of a finite geometric series as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842866). The size of said sub-tree is the distance between the first and second children, and, in fact, it is the same distance between all siblings since each of their sub-trees are the same size. If we call this distance `step`, then:
>
> 1st child is `N + 1`
>   2nd child is `N + 1 + step`
>   3rd child is `N + 1 + step + step`
>   ...and so on.

Can anyone provide a better explanation for how or why these formulas work?

Comment: This is probably a better match for math.stackexchange.com or perhaps cs.stackexchange.com, both of which allow mathjax, unlike this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the BFS:

If node `N` is at depth `D` and there is `a` nodes before `N` at depth `D` (and `b` nodes after):

```
N = K^0 + K^1 + ... + K^(D-1) + a
```

How many nodes will be labeled before its first child? There is `b` remaining nodes at depth `D` and `a * K` "child" nodes at depth `D+1` that will come before. So if `C` is the label of the first child of `N`:

```
C = N + b + a * K + 1
C = K^0 + K^1 + ... + K^(D-1) + a + b + a * K + 1
C = K^0 + K^1 + ... + K^(D-1) + K^D + a * K
```

Indeed there is `K^D` nodes at depth `D` so `a + b + 1 = K^D`, therefor:

```
C = 1 + (K^0 + ... + K^(D-2) + K^(D-1) + a )* K
C = 1 + N*k
```

For the DFS:

To compute the size of the step you have to compute the size of the remaining sub-tree, and like a sub-tree of a perfect K-ary tree is itself a perfect K-ary tree, you can compute its number of nodes.

Comment: Ah, I thought about formulating it terms of #-of-before nodes and #-of-after nodes, but was stuck there. Expanding `N` in terms of `K` was the insight I needed to understand the derivation. I think due to the very abstract nature of the problem, there is probably not a fundamentally simpler explanation than this one for the BFS case, and likewise for my explanation of the DFS case. I will accept this answer.