# How to find number of nodes from its leaves?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, quadtree

for a `k-ary` tree? Why is it `2L - 1` for a binary tree and not `4L - 1` for a quad tree?

Comment: 2L-1 is the simplifed form of the general formula. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842866/2223443

Comment: N = (k*L - 1) / (k-1) Thank you!